# How to get grouped looking UIActionSheet buttons when dynamically adding them

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactionsheet

Normally, when I add buttons to UIActionSheet statically like so:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: @"Yu", @"Gi", @"Oh", nil];
```

The appearance of the `UIActionSheet` will appear grouped like so, with the `Cancel` buttons a separate group:

[image]

However, as I would need to add my buttons dynamically depending on user actions, I found out that if I do so like this:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Yu"];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Gi"];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Oh"]; //This is just an example, could add more or less
```

The resulting `UIActionSheet` looks like this:

[image]

How would I be able to add buttons dynamically but still have them appear grouped as one would when adding buttons statically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Cancel button just like the others:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Yu"];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Gi"];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Oh"]; //This is just an example, could add more or less
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
```